# Full text search of documents on local harddrive and/or shared drive

Tags: windows, windows-xp, desktop-search

I am looking for free utility which will index my files in folder and its subfolders, or in network/shared drive.

It must support full text indexing for Office 2007 files, PDF, etc. I have seen Agen Ransac, however it doesn't show multiple results as Google does - which would make me very happy since I work as operator that needs info fast and easy.

**Application can not require** Administrator privileges to install/run.

Must run under Windows XP.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by `doesn't show multiple results as Google does`?

Comment: when you look for keyword at google, there are more results with piece of text that contains the keyword under it.. and there are few results with name of file, path and this sample text at least. However, in agent ransack, it shows me multiple results with names and paths of files but I must click everyone of them to see the content of file.

Comment: In Agent Ransack (2010) you can select all of the files in the list and it shows what I think you want in the right hand window - a list of tall the files found with a preview of the line(s) it found the text in.

Comment: Ransack requires admin right to install. :(

Answer (score 6):

Try **[Puggle](http://puggle.sourceforge.net/index.html)**. Since it has a [portable version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/puggle/files/puggle-portable/0.6/PugglePortableSearch.exe/download), you need no admin rights to run it.

Puggle is an open-source desktop search engine written exclusively in Java. It provides **full text and metadata search** over files, folders, music, photos, web pages and more that are stored locally on your computer. Supported file types are JPEG, PNG, GIF, TXT, PDF, DOC, RTF, WPD, HTML, XLS, PPT, ZIP, RAR, and MP3.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First I have made this answer, but then I realized Puggle has no way of seeing the full text and it wors more on title search than fulltext search :(

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html).

- supports all common document formats (OpenOffice, MS Office (old+XML formats), PDF, HTML, text,...)
- automatically updates its indexes when an indexed file changes
- has a portable version
- preview panel for looking at the texts that were found: http://sourceforge.net/project/screenshots.php?group_id=197779&ssid=91416
- Java software, cross-platform

Comment: Docfetcher got problem with showing result of full text search. When I click on the found doc - link, the content of file is showed as ASCII, not as "real content" aka real text

Answer (score 1):

[Gaviri SearchOS Free](http://www.gaviri.com/try-gaviri-searchos-free.php) is listed as a text-search product with a portable version
(however I have no experience with it).

Comment: Unsufficient search results.. =(

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/)</s>

**EDIT:** Question updated to clarify admin privileges requirement. Answer no longer valid.

Comment: it does require admin privileges to install

Comment: `it would be great if the application did not require Administrator privileges` - does my answer really deserve a -1???

Comment: admin priveleges is an optional requirement in your question

Comment: made it mandatory, wordiness of english =/ sry

Comment: no worries! I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

See also the following portable freewares:

[SearchMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_my_files.html)
[Index Your Files - X!](http://www.indexyourfiles.com/index.html)
[Locate32](http://www.locate32.net/)
[Ultra File Search](http://www.ultrafilesearch.com/)
[HABExam](http://www.hotkey.net.au/~hambar/habit/habutil.htm#juHABExam)
[File Seeker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/File-management/Windows-Portable-Applications-Portable-File-Seeker.shtml)
[LookDisk](http://www.fxsearch.com/ldw_eng/)
[Harddisk Search & Stats](http://www.harddisksearch.com/)

Comment: these are to find files OR do ascii fulltext search which is pretty much useless to me =/

Comment: UltraFileSearch - searches on filenames AND ascii full-text for me. I realise ASCII search might not be the best for your question.